# Is there a way to burn tokens only on transfer (on every transfer)

Tags: besu

If a transfer happens from one account to another thru metamask,how do we burn coins per transfer ? can this be done thru a contract? (using besu).

Is this change in java code or can be down thru a contract?

Answer (score 4):

That is called a Deflationary Token.

You can override the transfer function of an ERC-20 token and add a burn function that will burn a percentage of tokens that are being transferred.

Keep in mind that you should check both `from` and `to` addresses are non-zero, otherwise it would burn the `mint` and `burn` transfers.

Comment: Thanks trizin for the answer. I am new to the ethereum world. Is this change in java code or can be down thru a contract?

Comment: Is this change in java code or can be down thru a contract?

Comment: Must be done in contract

Comment: Can the basefee in 1599 be used or this  ?